# VBA - Worksheet Event

Tags: excel, vba, events

I receive every week a file that has always the same structure and format and what I want to do is to get a message when double clicking in some the cells of one of the columns.

I have the code and it works but I have to paste everytime in the worksheet once I open it. I want make this code "generic" so I can use it automatically everytime I open one of these workbooks without having to copy every time or do anything rather than the double clicking to get the message.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, cancel As   Boolean)
    If Not Application.Intersect(target, myrange) Is Nothing Then
        cancel = True
        MsgBox "some message"
    End If
End Sub
```

Some comments.. the sheet i need to work with it's always called the same and the column I need to work with is always the same too. The only change is the number of rows it contains.

After some research I don't know if I should do this in a class module or as an addi-in. I'm a begginer in VBA so this is out of my scope...yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Make it an AddIn and add a check for the filename

Comment: Or save the macro to your Personal workbook so that the code is also available with any other workbook you open, an example in [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav could explain me a bit more? I know how to save it as an AddIn but what do you mean by adding a check for the filename. Also, the filename does change (cause it has the date sent in it)

Comment: @Xabier where should I save it in the personal workbook and how for the code to be triggered with the double clicking event? Because if i write in a normal module it won't work.

Comment: maybe use the workbook version `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetbeforedoubleclick